# Wordpress上でPHPとHTMLを使って、formをPOST送信した後に確認画面で 画像を表示したい

Tags: php, wordpress, 画像, form

Wordpress上でPHPとHTMLを使って、フロントページ上のformから画像をアップロードし、POST送信した後に固定ページにおける確認画面で画像を表示したいです。

下記のサイトを参考にして遷移後のページにphpを記述していますが、アップロードは失敗しました。と表示されます。
おそらくWordpressにおける相対パスの記述が間違っていると思うのですが、どう表記したらいいかわかりません。
エラーの内容は

```
Warning:move_uploaded_ le(./img/20210217_1728.png):failed to open stream:
No such le or directory in  ~/~/page.php.on line 58
```

となります。

[画像ファイルのアップロード①(HTML+PHPのみ)](https://note.com/note256/n/n4b391f5457c0)

`$up_file = "img/". date("Ymd_His.") . mt_rand(1000,9999) . ".$ext";`
の `"img/"` の部分

分かる方いらっしゃいましたら教えていただけると助かります。

#### HTMLの記述

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ファイル送信ページ1</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file1.php">
<input type="file" name="up">
<input type="submit" value="アップロード">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

#### PHPの記述

```
<?php
$up_file = "";
$up_ok = false;
$tmp_file = isset($_FILES["up"]["tmp_name"]) ? $_FILES["up"]["tmp_name"] : "";
$org_file = isset($_FILES["up"]["name"]) ? $_FILES["up"]["name"] : "";
if( $tmp_file != "" &&
is_uploaded_file($tmp_file) )
{
$split = explode('.', $org_file); $ext = end($split);
if( $ext != "" &&
$ext != $org_file )
{
$up_file = "img/". date("Ymd_His.") . mt_rand(1000,9999) . ".$ext";
$up_ok = move_uploaded_file( $tmp_file, $up_file);
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ファイル受信ページ1</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><?php if( $up_ok ){ ?>
アップロードされたファイルは <img src="<?= $up_file ?>"> です。
<?php }else{ ?>
アップロードは失敗しました。
<?php } ?></p>
<a href="file1.html">アップロードページへ戻る</a>
</body>
</html>
```

質問者のみ

Comment: 実際にアップロードしたいディレクトリはどこになりますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！phpが記述されているファイルはpage.phpで、同じ階層にあるimgフォルダの中に画像をアップロードしたいです。

Answer (score 2):

問題解決しました。相対パスの書き方がわかっておりませんでした。

`$up_file = "img/"`　じゃなくて
`$up_file = "./img"`　と書いたら、

関数が機能して、imgフォルダの上の階層に
どこどこ写真ファイルが入るようになりました。